# Run-time error 1004 trying to use PivotFilters.Add method

Tags: vba, excel

Getting `Run-time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error`  with the below code - I've never used `.PivotFilters.Add` before, but the syntax looks to be correct... `mySheet` exists in the workbook, and so does `PivotTable1` and the field `Account Name`:

```
Sub TestFiltering()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

    'Error here
    mySheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Account Name").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotContain, Value1:="affiliate"

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: The syntax is correct. Where is the Account name field located in the pivot?

Comment: It's in the Filters. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes - you can't use filters there.

Comment: @Rory How inconvenient... I have a current solution that loops through all items and filters appropriately, but it's so slow that it's almost not even worth it. I guess there's no work around...

Comment: Depends if it's OLAP or not. Have you set the pivot table's `ManualUpdate` property to True while hiding items?

Comment: @Rory You mean set it to false? I just tried and still no real time difference, still takes 2-3 minutes while hiding items.

Comment: No, I mean set it to **True** while making the changes and then False at the end.

Comment: @Rory I see. Even with `ManualUpdate = True` it still takes a little while to run.

Comment: Might be an idea to post that as a new question - may have to be in Code Review though since it's working code, just slow. You could add it to your question here and I'll look it over.

Comment: @Rory Thank you Rory - I did post it in Code Review actually, and at the moment it looks like the solution is a long, convoluted function, so I'm working on setting that up now.

Comment: Great - good luck! :)